# Playing sound on hover images, stop when hovering off them

Tags: javascript, html, onhover, audio

I am trying to implement it so when I hover above the pulsing image(I know it looks cancerous) I want it to play a soundfile, and when I remove the mouse from the stacked images, the soundfile stops.

Another thing im struggeling with is to center the images, they seem to position themselvs in a corner no matter what, how may I fix this?
current code: cant seem to understand how to do so.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> fagdag 26.04.2016 helårs </title>
            <style>
            #banner {
            vertical-align: middle  
            }
            .pulsate {
            -webkit-animation: pulsate 3s ease-out;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
            opacity: 0.5;
            }
            @-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
                    0% { 
                    opacity: 0.5;
                }
                    50% { 
                    opacity: 1.0;
                }
                    100% { 
                    opacity: 0.5;
                }
            }



            </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="banner">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SrnpgpD.jpg" style="z-index: 0; position: absolute" align="middle"">
    <img class="pulsate" src="http://i.imgur.com/t2Pil1a.png" style="z-index: 1; position: absolute" align="middle""">
    </div>
    <p onmouseover="PlaySound('mySound')" 
    onmouseout="StopSound('mySound')">Hover Over Me To Play</p>
<br><br>
<audio id='mySound' src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/Cello_Live_Performance_John_Michel_Tchaikovsky_Violin_Concerto_3rd_MVT_applaused_cut.ogg'/>

    function PlaySound(soundobj) {
    var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj);
    thissound.play();
}

function StopSound(soundobj) {
    var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj);
    thissound.pause();
    thissound.currentTime = 0;
}

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: when I hover the images, the sound wont play

Comment: Is it loaded in the `cache` to be played ?

Comment: Im a newbie to this, what do you mean :3?

Comment: @Haliaka check the below. it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to add script tags to begin with.

To align text centrally you need to use `text-align:center`. Also, you should read up on `position:absolute` as this meant the `p` tag was hidden behind the image.

The below works when you hover over the image the sound will play.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>fagdag 26.04.2016 helårs</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="text-align:center;" id="banner">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SrnpgpD.jpg" style="z-index: 0;>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/t2Pil1a.png" style="z-index: 1; position: relative; text-align:center" class="pulsate">
  </div>
  <p onmouseover="PlaySound( 'mySound') " onmouseout="StopSound( 'mySound') ">Hover Over Me To Play</p>
  <audio id='mySound' src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/Cello_Live_Performance_John_Michel_Tchaikovsky_Violin_Concerto_3rd_MVT_applaused_cut.ogg' />

    <script type="text/javascript ">
      function PlaySound(soundobj) {
        var thissound = document.getElementById(soundobj);
        thissound.play();
      }

      function StopSound(soundobj) {
        var thissound = document.getElementById(soundobj);
        thissound.pause();
        thissound.currentTime = 0;
      }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How your JS is different that what OP has provided ?

Comment: Okay, thank you so much, can you also please help me with centering the image? :))))

Comment: you needed to use `text-align: center` in the div containing the image to center the image

Comment: @RayonDabre he was not using any script tags to begin with. You could not see the paragraph text he wanted to hover over as the image was covering it. He also wanted to center the image so this is now also being done

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald, Oops! I did not notice that :P

Comment: I tried using the text-align: center tag, but it only pushes it to the far right.

Comment: @Haliaka I am not sure why that was happening, but to align an element centrally you need to use `text-align:center`. are you happy with how the above works?

Comment: Im thankful for the sound, works like a charm, but the align seems to be acting a bit odd.

Comment: @Haliaka what is wrong with the alignment? the image is in the center, i thought that is what you wanted? make it full screen and you will see

Comment: Hmm.. When I run the code it appers in the very right cornor, might be my chrome whom is bugged? might be worth mentioning that the images are supposed to stack